# Why Does the Second Fundamental Form Restrict to Tangent Spaces?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, geodesic, connections

Let $(\tilde M, \tilde g)$ be a Riemannian manifold and $M$ be an embedded submanifold of $M$ with the induced Riemannian metric $g$.

On Pg. 138 of Lee's *Riemannian Geometry - An Introduction to Curvature*, the following is written:

> *For any vector $V\in T_pM$, $II(V, V)$ is the $\tilde g$-acceleration at $p$ of the $g$-geodesic $\gamma_V$.*

Here $II$ denotes the second fundamental form.

This seems to suggest that for vector fields $X$ and $Y$ on $M$, the second fundamental form $II(X, Y)$ at the point $p\in M$ depends only on the value $X(p)$ and $Y(p)$.

**But why is this so?** By definition $II(X, Y)(p)$ is the orthogonal projection on $(T_pM)^\perp$ of the vector $(\tilde\nabla_X(Y))(p)$. (Here $\tilde\nabla$ is the Riemannian connection on $\tilde M$.)

I know that $(\tilde\nabla_XY)(p)$ depends only on the value taken by $X$ at the point $p$, and the values taken by $Y$ on a curve in $M$ which is tangent to $X(p)$. But $(\tilde\nabla_XY)(p)$ is not determined solely by $X(p)$ and $Y(p)$.

Can somebody please clear this confusion. Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at Lemma 8.1 in my book. It answers exactly this question.

Comment: @JackLee Part (a) of Lemma 8.1 reads 'The second fundamental form is independent of the extensions of $X$ and $Y$'. I read it as 'Let $X$ and $Y$ be vector fields on $M$, then the second fundamental form is independent of the extensions of $X$ and $Y$ to $\tilde M$.' But a careful reading of the proof given in the book makes it clear that here $X$ and $Y$ need not be vector fields but just two vectors in a tangent space.

Comment: I see what you mean. I'll make sure that the wording is clearer in the second edition.

Comment: Oh so there's going to be a second edition! Great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Del}{\tilde{\nabla}}\newcommand{\Brak}[1]{\left\langle #1\right\rangle}$Let $p$ be a point of $M$, and let $N$ be an arbitrary smooth normal field to $M$ in some neighborhood of $p$. If $Y$ is a tangent field near $p$, then since $\Brak{N, Y} = 0$ pointwise,
$$
0 = X\Brak{Y, N} = \Brak{\Del_{X}Y, N} + \Brak{Y, \Del_{X}N}.
$$
Particularly, $\Brak{\Del_{X}Y, N} = -\Brak{Y, \Del_{X}N}$ depends only on the value of $Y$ at $p$. Since $N$ was arbitrary, the normal component of $\Del_{X}Y$, i.e., $II(X, Y)$, depends only on the values $X(p)$ and $Y(p)$.